# Different sizes ( Ant x Eclipse )

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, war

i'm generating a war with an Ant script but i noticed that the Ant's war size is almost double the size of the war created by Eclipse. And now i'm want to know if it's possible to reduce this size.

This is the war script:

```
<war destfile="${docflow4-web-home}/deploy/docflow.war" webxml="${docflow4-web-home}/web/WEB-INF/web.xml">
        <classes dir="${docflow4-web-home}/web/WEB-INF/classes" />
        <lib dir="${docflow4-web-home}/web/WEB-INF/lib"/> 
        <fileset dir="${docflow4-web-home}/web">
            <include name="**/*.*"/>                                
        </fileset>          
    </war>
```

Comment: check if your classes aren't being copied twice and also compression options

Comment: oh you were right! Dumb mistake hehe, thanks for the hand. :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer to my problem was to remove the "class" and the "lib" tag from the script, they were duplicating the files

```
<war destfile="${docflow4-web-home}/deploy/docflow.war" webxml="${docflow4-web-home}/web/WEB-INF/web.xml">        
    <fileset dir="${docflow4-web-home}/web">
        <include name="**/*.*"/>                                
    </fileset>          
</war>
```